# How to resolve 'auth/firebase-app-check-token-is-invalid' in react using reCAPTCHA Enterprise?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I am using Firebase app-check in react application to verify the login request; at first, I register for the RecapchaEnterprise and get the site key and secret key. Then I put the site key in the Firebase app-check under app-check where I clicked on the register app and set the site key.
Then for the firebase initilization, I am using this:

```
export const app = ()=>{
  const lapp = firebase.initializeApp({
    ...firebaseConfig,
  })
  const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(lapp, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider('site-key'),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true 
  });
  return lapp
}
```

After initializing the project to login, I am using this:

```
export async function firebaseLogin(email, password, success, needOtp, errorCallback) {
  const auth = getAuth()
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      success(user)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

But still, after calling the `firebaseLogin`  method, it returns `auth/firebase-app-check-token-is-invalid` Did I miss any steps for firebase app-check I follow the docs and it does not say anything else.

Comment: did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: I am also curious about a solution to this.  I'm experiencing this with @angular/fire